# Convert binary to decimal in the given sequence

Tags: sql, oracle, binary

I have a requirement to convert the binary number to decimal. The converted decimal range would be no greater than 256. (100 Million in binary)

It involves an iOS app, where to read a problem investigation report, four binary integers are dynamically chosen and base on tht. (Some UI stuffs inside with 0s and 1s).

Then, we would concatenate them with '.' as delimiter.(similar to a IP address)
Based on the final Sequence formed, we fetch the report id after converting them into decimals.

Say, `10.100.1.11`(Input) could become `2.4.1.3`(Output)

Have been going through numerous reports and Objective-C. Literally lost my mind. Being in iOS dev, I couldnt get a PL/SQL compiled. So, I have to accomplish with a SQL.

**EDIT:**

Luckily, I was able to write something like this. (but just one number at a time :( )

```
SQL> var NUM number;
SQL> exec :NUM := 100000000;

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> SELECT SUM(value)
FROM
  (SELECT POWER(2,LENGTH(TO_CHAR(:NUM))-level)*to_number(SUBSTR(TO_CHAR(:NUM),level,1),'FM9') AS value
  FROM DUAL
    CONNECT BY level <= LENGTH(TO_CHAR(:NUM))
  );  2    3    4    5    6

SUM(VALUE)
----------
       256
```

Comment: @Ben 10 in Binary is 2 in Decimal.. 100 is 3...etc..

Comment: @MaheswaranRavisankar `100 is 3` is not true... (its 4) ;)

Comment: @user2989408 `2:00 AM` effect, In question I have it right, sorry!!

Comment: No problems.. I am already confused!

Comment: @Mahesh Have you tried [CAST_TO_NUMBER](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/u_raw.htm#BABGHJBD).

Comment: @user2989408 gives `ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error` in the function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are different ways you can approach this.  So, I'm choosing what might seem like a rather arcane way.  The motivation for this is that `to_number()` accepts hexadecimal formats but not binary formats.  What would be so hard about supporting binary and octal as well as hex?  Well, that's not a question for me to ask.  Oracle doesn't.

But, we can sort of readily convert from binary to hex.  You are only dealing with 8 binary digits, so that is only two hex digits.  Here is the code:

```
with bin2hex as (
      select '0000' as bin, '0' as hex from dual union all
      select '0001' as bin, '1' as hex from dual union all
      select '0010' as bin, '2' as hex from dual union all
      select '0011' as bin, '3' as hex from dual union all
      select '0100' as bin, '4' as hex from dual union all
      select '0101' as bin, '5' as hex from dual union all
      select '0110' as bin, '6' as hex from dual union all
      select '0111' as bin, '7' as hex from dual union all
      select '1000' as bin, '8' as hex from dual union all
      select '1001' as bin, '9' as hex from dual union all
      select '1010' as bin, 'A' as hex from dual union all
      select '1011' as bin, 'B' as hex from dual union all
      select '1100' as bin, 'C' as hex from dual union all
      select '1101' as bin, 'D' as hex from dual union all
      select '1110' as bin, 'E' as hex from dual union all
      select '1111' as bin, 'F' as hex from dual
     )
select t.*, c1.bin as bin1, c2.bin as bin2, c1.hex as hex1, c2.hex as hex2,
       to_number(c2.hex||c1.hex, 'xx')
from (select '10010010' as num from dual union all
      select '10010' from dual
     ) t left outer join
     bin2hex c1
     on substr('00000000'||t.num, -4) = c1.bin left outer join
     bin2hex c2
     on substr('00000000'||t.num, -8, 4) = c2.bin;
```

Answer (score 3):

Just for fun, a version using a recursive CTE (so requires 11gR2), because apparently I look for any excuse to play with these at the moment:

```
with data as (
 select '10.100.1.11' as str from dual
),
t as (
 select level as pos,
 regexp_substr(str, '[^\.]+', 1, level) as val
 from data
 connect by level <= regexp_count(str, '[^\.]+')
),
r (pos, val, len, lvl, pos_val) as (
 select pos, val, length(val), 0, 0
 from t
 union all
 select pos, val, len, lvl + 1,
 power(2, lvl) * substr(val, len - lvl, 1)
 from r
 where lvl < length(val)
)
select listagg(sum(pos_val), '.') within group (order by pos)
from r
group by pos;


2.4.1.3
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/24348).

Still not as arcane as Gordon's though...

Answer (score 1):

```
with bin2hex as (
 select '0000' as bin, '0' as hex from dual union all
 select '0001' as bin, '1' as hex from dual union all
 select '0010' as bin, '2' as hex from dual union all
 select '0011' as bin, '3' as hex from dual union all
 select '0100' as bin, '4' as hex from dual union all
 select '0101' as bin, '5' as hex from dual union all
 select '0110' as bin, '6' as hex from dual union all
 select '0111' as bin, '7' as hex from dual union all
 select '1000' as bin, '8' as hex from dual union all
 select '1001' as bin, '9' as hex from dual union all
 select '1010' as bin, 'A' as hex from dual union all
 select '1011' as bin, 'B' as hex from dual union all
 select '1100' as bin, 'C' as hex from dual union all
 select '1101' as bin, 'D' as hex from dual union all
 select '1110' as bin, 'E' as hex from dual union all
 select '1111' as bin, 'F' as hex from dual
 )
select LISTAGG(t.num,'.')WITHIN GROUP (order by row_label) as source,
       LISTAGG(c1.bin,'.') WITHIN GROUP (order by row_label) as bin1,
       LISTAGG(c2.bin,'.') WITHIN GROUP (order by row_label) as bin2,
       LISTAGG(c1.hex,'.')WITHIN GROUP (order by row_label) as hex,
       LISTAGG(to_number(c2.hex||c1.hex, 'xx') ,'.') WITHIN GROUP (order by row_label) as deci
     -- c1.bin as bin1, c2.bin as bin2, c1.hex as hex1, c2.hex as hex2,
 --to_number(c2.hex||c1.hex, 'xx')
from (SELECT level as row_label,REGEXP_SUBSTR('10.100.1.11','[^.]+',1,LEVEL) AS num
  FROM dual
CONNECT BY REGEXP_SUBSTR('10.100.1.11','[^.]+',1,LEVEL) IS NOT NULL
 ) t left outer join
 bin2hex c1
 on substr('00000000'||t.num, -4) = c1.bin left outer join
 bin2hex c2
 on substr('00000000'||t.num, -8, 4) = c2.bin;
```

**Result:**

```
SOURCE      BIN1                BIN2                HEX     DECI
10.100.1.11 0010.0100.0001.0011 0000.0000.0000.0000 2.4.1.3 2.4.1.3
```

**demo**: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/477a3/15)

Answer (score 1):

Somewhat inspired by Gordon's approach, here's a non-recursive version:

```
with data as (
 select '10.100.1.11' as str from dual
),
t as (
 select level as pos,
 lpad(regexp_substr(str, '[^\.]+', 1, level),  16, '0') as val
 from data
 connect by level <= regexp_count(str, '[^\.]+')
),
r as (
  select power(2, level - 1) as digit_val,
    lpad(power(10, level - 1), 16, '0') as raw_val,
    lpad('0', 16, '0') as zero_val
  from dual
  connect by level <= 16
)
select listagg(sum(
  case when utl_raw.bit_and(t.val, r.raw_val) = r.zero_val then 0 else 1 end 
    * r.digit_val), '.') within group (order by pos)
from t
cross join r
group by pos;

2.4.1.3
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/24401).

In this version `r` is generating all the binary values and their decimal equivalents, and the main query is treating those and the original 'octet' as raw to do a `bit_and` operation to decide if that bit is set, and therefore whether the decimal equivalent should be included in the `sum`.

This will handle binary values up to 16 digits, which is more than needed here; but 8 isn't enough and 9 seemed wrong somehow...

Answer (score 1):

I made also a version based on Gordon Linoff solution, that is more generic(you can easily put in larger numbers)

```
with bin2hex as (
      select '0000' as bin, '0' as hex from dual union all
      select '0001' as bin, '1' as hex from dual union all
      select '0010' as bin, '2' as hex from dual union all
      select '0011' as bin, '3' as hex from dual union all
      select '0100' as bin, '4' as hex from dual union all
      select '0101' as bin, '5' as hex from dual union all
      select '0110' as bin, '6' as hex from dual union all
      select '0111' as bin, '7' as hex from dual union all
      select '1000' as bin, '8' as hex from dual union all
      select '1001' as bin, '9' as hex from dual union all
      select '1010' as bin, 'A' as hex from dual union all
      select '1011' as bin, 'B' as hex from dual union all
      select '1100' as bin, 'C' as hex from dual union all
      select '1101' as bin, 'D' as hex from dual union all
      select '1110' as bin, 'E' as hex from dual union all
      select '1111' as bin, 'F' as hex from dual
     )
select listagg(hex) within group (order by lv desc), 
       to_number(listagg(hex) within group (order by lv desc), LPAD('x', max(lv), 'x'))
from(
select substr('0000'||num, -4*level, 4) bin, level lv
from (select '1001010100000010111110010000000' num --change value here
        from dual
     ) a
     connect by level<=ceil(length(a.num)/4)) a
join bin2hex b on b.bin=a.bin
```

Answer (score 1):

A not so arcane version...

```
with bit as (
  select '0' b from dual union all
  select '1' from dual
),
bin2dec as (
  select b7.b || b6.b || b5.b || b4.b || b3.b || b2.b || b1.b || b0.b bin,
         b7.b*128+b6.b*64+b5.b*32+b4.b*16+b3.b*8+b2.b*4+b1.b*2+b0.b*1 dec
  from bit b0
  cross join bit b1
  cross join bit b2
  cross join bit b3
  cross join bit b4
  cross join bit b5
  cross join bit b6
  cross join bit b7
),
testdata as (
  select '10010010' as num from dual union all
  select '10010' from dual
)

select testdata.num, bin2dec.dec from testdata join bin2dec
on substr('00000000'||testdata.num,-8) = bin2dec.bin
```

... well in fact a very basic one based on the [conversion from binary to decimal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_number#Decimal) as we learned it at school. By the use of some cross joins, I build all combinations of 8 bits, storing both their binary representation and their decimal value. After that, the conversion by itself is a simple lookup into that table.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying this on `Oracle` using `CONNECT BY` to convert binary to decimal in simple `SELECT` statement. Finally got the desired output using below code.

```
WITH INPUT AS
(SELECT REVERSE('&N') AS X FROM DUAL)
SELECT SUM(TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(X,LEVEL,1)*POWER(2,LEVEL-1))) AS OUTPUT
FROM INPUT CONNECT BY LEVEL<=LENGTH(X);
```